# Rank-ordered statistics of a data time series

Tags: regression, time-series, ranking

I have a time series of observations $(x_t)_{1\leq t\leq T}$ that I can order into $(x_n)_{1\leq n\leq N}$, with $N = T$ such that $x_n<x_{n+1}$ and $x_1=\min{x_t}$ and $x_N=\max{x_t}$.

Then I pair up the data and construct $(y_n)_{1\leq n\leq N/2}$, with $y_n=(x_n + x_{N-n+1})/2$, and $(z_n)_{1\leq n\leq N/2}$, with $z_n=(x_n^2 + x_{N-n+1}^2)/2$.

I now linearly regress $(y_n)_{1\leq n\leq N/2}$ vs. $(z_n)_{1\leq n\leq N/2}$ and obtain

$$y_n = c + bz_n + e_n,$$

where $(e_n)_{1\leq n\leq N/2}$ is the regression error. I get a pretty good fit ($R^2 > 0.90$).

The questions are: what does it tell about the data, what is the meaning of the coefficient $b$, how does it relate to the standard skewness of the distribution or to maybe a Spearman's rho of some sort, in a word, what have I demonstrated?

Comment: Did you come up with this just randomly, or did you have some ideas that led you to the expression?

Comment: I had some ideas. If the underlying were normal (or symmetrical), I would have expected $b =0$. Since the distribution is skewed, this property shows up. What I am trying to establish is, if $x_t$ is a linear function like $c + a\epsilon_t+b\epsilon_t^2$, with $\epsilon_t$ a somewhat symmetrical process (say standard normal), then I would have, as a property, that $\mathbb{E}[x_t] = c + a\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t]+ b\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t^2]=c + b\mathbb{V}[\epsilon_t]$. I do not believe that this particular $b$ is the same as the one that I have in the rank-ordered regression. That's the question.